# Error checking Ints with thousands separator Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'd like to error check integer entries in Swift so that:

1. those integers without thousands separators are accepted,
2. those integers with thousands separators in the right places are accepted,
3. those integers with thousands separators in the wrong places are rejected, and
4. non-integers are rejected.

I believe that I have a solution which satisfies 1, 2, and 4, but not yet 3.

```
func makeInt( incoming: String ) {
    let tempValue = Int( incoming.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( thousandSeparator, withString: "" ).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet() ) )
    if tempValue != nil {
        print( tempValue! )
    }
    else {
        print( "Life hurts" )
    }
}

makeInt( "1000" ) --> 1000
makeInt( "1,000" ) --> 1000
makeInt( "10,00" ) --> 1000 *Should be Life hurts*
makeInt( "doggy" ) --> Life hurts
```

The next place I would go with this would be to set up a regular expression that maps to thousands separators in thousands places, but before I went there, I was curious if anyone had any other way to do this as it would seem to be a fairly common need.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don´t you use the users locale to scan in the number and then you have it without thousand's separator. Some countries write i.e. 10.00.000,00 (I think India)

Comment: @HannesSverrisson Exactly, this is more complex than just "every other symbol should be a `,`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do regex to check the formatting, but probably easier is to use the existing `NSNumberFormatter` which does this sort of validation for you, e.g.:

```
let formatter: NSNumberFormatter = {
    let _formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    _formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    return _formatter
}()
```

And then

```
func makeInt(incoming: String) {
    guard let value = formatter.numberFromString(incoming) else {
        print("Life hurts")
        return
    }

    print(value.integerValue)
}
```

This demonstrates the behavior you describe. It also then supports localization (where the thousands separator is automatically determined from the user's locale).

Comment: That closure is a sick way to initialize objects that need some extra steps. neat!